# Why am I getting wrong time output with correct timezone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timezone, output

Why am I getting this output time:

2013-01-12 18:24:37.783 Code testings[10328:c07] 0001-01-01 17:12:52 +0000

when I run this code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.hour   = 17;
components.minute = 47;
components.second = 0;

NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@", fire);
```

I have tried default timezone, system timezone. And it always gives me an output with different minutes and seconds! plus wrong date 0001-01-01!!!! Any idea why?

Additional Tests:

When running this code:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
components.hour   = (components.hour + 1) % 24;
components.minute = 0;
components.second = 0;
NSDate *fire = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@", fire);
```

It gives me this output:

2013-01-12 18:41:41.552 Code testings[10648:c07] 0001-01-01 18:25:52 +0000

2013-01-12 18:42:16.274 Code testings[10648:c07] 0001-01-01 18:25:52 +0000

2013-01-12 18:42:30.310 Code testings[10648:c07] 0001-01-01 18:25:52 +0000

Comment: Can you tell me, what you want to perform, your requirement?

Comment: for now firing a notification.. but it's the general behaviour I was wondering about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mising the year, month and day components.

Do:

`NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:[NSDate date]];`

Now that should give you the correct date.

Side note: since the `NSCalendarUnit` is a bitfield typedef for `NSUInteger`, I pass in `NSUIntegerMax` to retrieve all possible calendar units. That way I don't have to have a massive bitwise OR statement.

Comment: nice trick with NSUIntegerMax, but as Whylonely seems to be a beginner, you should probably explain that. anyway +1

Comment: I don't take credit for it though, it's a trick I learned here on SO :)

Comment: @PeterWarbo Thanks for the smart answer. NSUIntegerMax it helped me a lot.

Comment: Always thought there had to be a better way than having a super long bitwise `or` statement, awesome tip with `NSUIntegerMax`!

Answer (score 4):

You also need to request the year, month and day with the `calendar components:` method.

From Apple docs:

> An instance of NSDateComponents is not responsible for answering
>   questions about a date beyond the information with which it was
>   initialized.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

NSLog of the date will display the time with the  default timezone.